# Hourly automation with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have had some success with Windows scheduler to run daily reports in pandas. The workflow is basically read a .csv file, do some things to it, save the modified file.

Are there modules to do something like this hourly without human intervention? I would read all of the files in a directory, append them into a single file, drop duplicates, apply some changes (add some columns, perform some calculations on timestamps), and then save the consolidated new file in another directory.

I am most familiar with pandas but I can incorporate some other techniques.

Comment: Are you basicalliy asking how to run a script every hour, or do you want it controlled from within python? Because in the latter case, you need to keep the process running forever, in the former you only need to schedule it. And is it still Windows we're talking about? Otherwise I'd suggest cron jobs.

Comment: Yes, it is on Windows. Well, for the processing of the information I would like to continue to use pandas, in particular, since I familiar with it and I know exactly how to process the files to get the desired results. So this could be running an ipython notebook every 1 hour automatically or some other solution.

Comment: Try Celery: http://www.celeryproject.org  This is the CronTab scheduler http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: Thanks Alexander, that looks pretty good. So, I import crontab into my ipython notebook and it will continue to run as long as the computer is on and ipython is running? I can still use that and a normal pandas notebook, right?